# Using "oneway void" in Thrift function definitions

Tags: erlang, thrift, thrift-protocol

I'm using a `oneway` modifier in one of my Thrift function definitions:

```
...
oneway void secret_function(1: string x, 2: string y),
...
```

When generating the respective Erlang code via Thrift, this is translated into:

```
...
function_info('secret_function', reply_type) ->
  oneway_void;
function_info('secret_function', exceptions) ->
  {struct, []};
...
```

Please note the `oneway_void` atom there.

When the `secret_function` function is executed, I get the following error:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 2-Sep-2010::18:17:08 ===
oneway void secret_function threw error which must be ignored: {error,
                                                             function_clause,
                                                             [{thrift_protocol,
                                                               term_to_typeid,
                                                               [oneway_void]},
                                                              {thrift_protocol,
                                                               struct_write_loop,
                                                               3},
                                                              {thrift_protocol,
                                                               write,2},
                                                              {thrift_processor,
                                                               send_reply,
                                                               4},
                                                              {thrift_processor,
                                                               handle_function,
                                                               2},
                                                              {thrift_processor,
                                                               loop,1}]}
```

Independently from the possible bugs contained in the user code, here the `thrift_protocol:term_to_typeid/1` function is being called with the `oneway_void` atom as an argument, which causes a function clause. In fact, reading from the code (thrift_protocol.erl):

```
...
term_to_typeid(void) -> ?tType_VOID;
term_to_typeid(bool) -> ?tType_BOOL;
term_to_typeid(byte) -> ?tType_BYTE;
term_to_typeid(double) -> ?tType_DOUBLE;
term_to_typeid(i16) -> ?tType_I16;
term_to_typeid(i32) -> ?tType_I32;
term_to_typeid(i64) -> ?tType_I64;
term_to_typeid(string) -> ?tType_STRING;
term_to_typeid({struct, _}) -> ?tType_STRUCT;
term_to_typeid({map, _, _}) -> ?tType_MAP;
term_to_typeid({set, _}) -> ?tType_SET;
term_to_typeid({list, _}) -> ?tType_LIST.
...
```

A bug? Any other explanation? Why is `oneway_void` being passed to that function?

Comment: As far as I know Erlang thrift bindings are quite mediocre, so it's quite possible it's a bug

Comment: What does `secret_function/2` look like? How does it call `term_to_typeid/1`? I have no knowledge of thrift but looking at the functions should tell you.

Comment: @rvirding: I've added the full stack trace. There's nothing there directly related to my own functions. My feeling is that something is wrong in the secret_function/2, and that the real error is "eaten" by Thrift, which is printing just that section of the stack trace, making hard to identify the reason of the error itself. Trying to do some tracing now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what's going on behind the scenes.

My Erlang code (the `secret_function/2`) was returning {ok, pid()} rather than simply ok.
Even if this is conceptually wrong since I declared the function `oneway_void`, it took me a while  to identify the cause of the problem.
Maybe we could adjust the `handle_succes` function in Thrift so that it behaves the same way the h`andle_function_catch` already does.
This is how the `handle_function_catch` looks like at the moment:

```
...
case {ErrType, ErrData} of
    _ when IsOneway ->
        Stack = erlang:get_stacktrace(),
        error_logger:warning_msg(
          "oneway void ~p threw error which must be ignored: ~p",
          [Function, {ErrType, ErrData, Stack}]),
        {State, ok};
...
```

Even if the function is declared as `oneway_void`, when an exception is raised, the problem is reported. A potential new handle_success function, following the same reasoning, could then look like the following:

```
handle_success(State = #thrift_processor{service = Service},
               Function,
               Result) ->
    ReplyType  = Service:function_info(Function, reply_type),
    StructName = atom_to_list(Function) ++ "_result",

    case Result of
        {reply, ReplyData} when ReplyType =:= oneway_void ->
            Stack = erlang:get_stacktrace(),
            error_logger:warning_msg(
              "oneway void ~p sent reply which must be ignored: ~p",
              [Function, {ReplyData, Stack}]),
            {State, ok};
                {reply, ReplyData} ->
            Reply = {{struct, [{0, ReplyType}]}, {StructName, ReplyData}},
            send_reply(State, Function, ?tMessageType_REPLY, Reply);

        ok when ReplyType == {struct, []} ->
            send_reply(State, Function, ?tMessageType_REPLY, {ReplyType, {StructName}});

        ok when ReplyType == oneway_void ->
            %% no reply for oneway void
            {State, ok}
    end.
```

Here I'm just checking if the function is defined as `oneway_void` and if this is true and I still receive a return value different from the atom `ok`, I report the accident, still ignoring the return value.

This is what a developer would see with the updated `handle_success` function:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 7-Sep-2010::11:06:43 ===
oneway void secret_function sent reply which must be ignored: {{ok,
                                                                  <0.262.0>},
                                                                 []}
```

And that could save your life at least once (cit.).